# Select Options is not updated

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the select of the cities based on the Country previous selection

The alert is displaying the option correctly from the json response.

```
$('#property_country').change(function() {
  var selectedCountryId = this.value;
  var $city = $('#property_city');
  var options = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Lookup',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      action: "getCities",
      countryId: selectedCountryId
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(jsonResponse) {
    $.each(jsonResponse, function(index, item) {
      $.each(item, function(index, item) {
        console.log(item.CityId + " " + item.CityName);
        options = options + '<option value="' + item.CityId + '"> ' + item.CityName + '</option>';
      });
    });
    alert(options);
    $city.html(options);
  });

});
```

Comment: Nothing obvious in code shown that would cause any issues. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: You have a nested `$.each` with same parameter names `item` and `index`. That might not have caused the issue here but, what does `jsonResponse` look like? Assuming, `jsonResponse` is an array of cities, do you need the second `$.each`?

Comment: Here is the json response
 {"Cities":
 [
  {"CityId":"1","CityName":"Al Quds"},
  {"CityId":"2","CityName":"Ramllah"},
  {"CityId":"3","CityName":"Nablus"},
  {"CityId":"4","CityName":"Hebron"}
 ]
  } 
And below also the the Html Print for the alert which should be added to the the Select : 

<option value="1">Al Quds</option>
<option value="2">Ramllah</option>
<option value="3">Nablus</option>
<option value="4">Hebron</option>

But regardless to all of the above .append or .html is not updating the select #property_city even if it's static